# Splash screen and Install dialog show black background behind app icon

Tags: icons, progressive-web-apps, appicon

I'm having trouble with the icon that is shown for my PWA as:

- splash screen icon
- icon that is shown in the "Install app" dialog

See splash screen: (it's already fading out to the app a little bit, sorry about that):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BqXU.png

And the Install dialog:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGuZJ.png

My icons (up to 512x512) are just circular, with transparent backgrounds. I created them using a PWA icon generator website. The icon looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykmYG.png

Does anyone know why the icon is shown with a black background in the splash screen and in the Install app dialog?

My app manifest declares both the title bar color and the background color as #fafafa (almost white).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think this might vary by platform. Where is this? Android? iOS? desktop? Have tried it on other platforms?

Answer (score 0):

I changed png to jpg image. It works for me
{
"src": "icon-48x48.jpg",
"sizes": "48x48",
"type": "image/jpg",
"purpose": "maskable any"
},